# Returning same method being called

Tags: javascript

I have following code, I am expecting `alert('baz')` but it is not working

```
var foo = function () {
    function foo() {
        alert('foo');
    }
    foo.baz = function () {
        alert('baz');
    }

}
foo().baz();
```

However If I `return foo` at the end it works

```
var foo = function () {
    function foo() {
        alert('foo');
    }
    foo.baz = function () {
        alert('baz');
    }
    return foo;
}
foo().baz(); // output:baz
```

why first one not working and why second is working and what is purpose inner `foo`??

Comment: *"and what is purpose inner `foo`"* It doesn't seem to have any purpose since it is never called. You would achieve the same effect by returning a simple object: `return {baz: function() { ... }};`.

Comment: I guess, the inner `foo()` appears to be a constructor.

Comment: @Xufox  then `foo` should be alert??

Comment: @ozil Actually, I wanted to write “is supposed to be a constructor”. Because it looks like one but obviously doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

Because chaining method needs to be returned something. So, in your code you are correctly returning the foo and then it's getting called.

Comment: which `foo` is returning in `return statement` outer or inner

Comment: @ozil: The one closest in scope, which is the inner one.

Comment: @Felix Kling if it is inner one then how `foo().baz();` works?

Comment: @ozil: I'm not sure I understand the question. Can you elaborate on what confuses you?

Comment: @FelixKling the thing is When I debug this `foo().baz();` `foo` is return which is `inner function` as you said, if it inner function then how does it know about `baz` and calls it

Comment: @ozil:  `foo().baz()` calls the outer `foo` and access the `baz` property of the return value. The return value is the inner `foo`, as we already said. You are explicitly making `baz` a property of the inner `foo`: `foo.baz = function () {...}`. Maybe you understood it better if you chose a different name for inner `foo`. As I already said in another comment, the fact that the inner `foo` is a functions is irrelevant, since it's never called. You could as well do `var foo = {}; foo.baz = ...;` instead.

Comment: @ozil: To be clear, neither the outer function nor the inner function calls `baz`. *You* are calling `baz` with `foo().baz()`.

Comment: @FelixKling Then why `return foo` require with out it it does not alert.

Comment: @ozil: Because if you don't return anything, the outer function will return `undefined`. `undefined.baz()` is an error.

Comment: @FelixKling Sorry, I am not getting the point. can you please explain me the execution flow?

Comment: @ozil: In the first case: 1. Assign function to  `foo`. 2. Call `foo`. 3. Define function `foo`. 4. Assign function to `foo.baz`. 5. Return `undefined`. 6. Access property `baz` of return value (`undefined`). 7. ERROR. In the second case: : 1. Assign function to  `foo`. 2. Call `foo`. 3. Define function `foo`. 4. Assign function to `foo.baz`. 5. Return `foo`. 6. Access property `baz` of return value (`foo`). 7. Call function `baz`. 8. Call `alert`.

Comment: @ozil: Let me simplify your question/example: First example: `function foo() { var bar = 42;}; console.log(foo() + 1)`. Second example: `function foo() { var bar = 42; return bar; }; console.log(foo() + 1)`. Your basically asking why the second example results in `43` while the first one doesn't. The answer is that the second function returns something and the first one doesn't . There really isn't anything complicated about it. Again, it might be clearer if you didn't use the same variable inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is not working, because the "foo" method is not a void, so it expects a return value. Without a return value, the call to the method will fail. I advice you to trace both of the calls in developer tools, breakpoint each and trace step by step the chain of events.

As for your second question, The purpose is simple, to give foo additional functionality. Usually you won't use nested foo, it's a bad practice, but a prototype. As with an account method. It contains first name, last name and account number, then a prototype of the method is created in order to create withdraw and deposit methods for the specific account.

It's almost identical to working with polymorphic objects in C# or JAVA. instead using override, you use prototype, or in the case of the code above, nested "foo".

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are assigning the function to a variable and not normally. The variable name can be used by the code inside the function to refer the function itself, but the code outside the function can not see it at all.

When you call the function like **foo().baz();**
it will first call the **foo()** function and will need a return value (in this case a function referer variable). Then according to the referer variable name it will call the **baz()** inside the **foo()**. So to call the function baz() inside foo(), you need to access function first.